# How to store and query a flat file containing JSON string as a part of each line, into a hive table ?

Tags: json, hive, hdfs

I have a plane text file in HDFS as

> 44,UK,{"name":{"name1":"John","name2":"marry","name3":"michel"},"fruits":{"fruit1":"apple","fruit2":"orange"}},31-07-2016
>
> 91,INDIA,{"name":{"name1":"Ram","name2":"Sam"},"fruits":{}},31-07-2016

and want to store this in a hive table with schema as

> *create table data (SerNo int, country string , detail string,date string )*

Then what should be the table definition so that {"name": ..... } will come as one column as "detail" and rest with other ?
what should be the column separator ? so that i can query detail column with **get_json_object** udf along with other columns.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hive works well with Json format data until Json file is not nested at many levels. In that case it is better to make your Json file more Flat.

refer https://pkghosh.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/hive-plays-well-with-json/

Here you can find explained answer for you question.

Comment: Thanks @siddhartha. But I want to store JSON string part into a separate column so that I can use UDF to query.  But if I put whole string as one column as you say , then how can we query serno,country and date using get_json_object UDF as these are not part of JSON string.